# Por que, além de imprimir o resultado esperado, console.log também imprime undefined?

Tags: javascript, console, undefined

Estou seguindo um exemplo de um curso e fiquei com a dúvida de por que, neste código:

```
function area(largura, altura) {
    const area = largura * altura;
    if(area > 20) {
        console.log(`Valor acima do permitido: ${area}m2.`);
    } else {
        return area;
    }
};

console.log(area(5, 5));
```

Depois de executado o resultado também dará `undefined`?

```
Valor acima do permitido: 25m2.
undefined
```

Sei que tem outras maneiras melhores de fazer esse código, mas quero entender o porquê do `undefined`.

Comment: Se a condição `if(area > 20)` for `true`, qual será o retorno da função `area`?

Answer (score 2):

Isso acontece porque o Console do navegador (ou algum REPL — como o do Node.js) exibem o resultado da avaliação do código que nele será avaliado.

Supomos que você insira a expressão `4 + 4` no Console. O *runtime* avaliará a expressão e retornar o seu resultado. Nesse exemplo, será `8`.

No caso de funções, o Console imprimirá o resultado da avaliação da função que é, em última instância, o próprio valor de retorno da aplicação da função.

Mais especificamente, em relação ao `console.log`, trata-se de uma função que retorna o valor `undefined`. Desse modo, embora o `console.log` também imprima as menagens no Console, por último, será impresso o próprio valor de retorno da função, que, no caso de `console.log`, é `undefined`.

---

Você pode verificar o valor de retorno do `console.log`:

```js
const result = console.log('Foo!'); // Irá imprimir "Foo!", mas o valor retornado é `undefined`.

console.log('Resultado:', result); //=> Resultado: undefined
console.log('Igual a undefined?', result === undefined); //=> true
```